# Tinymce editor stripping the script tag in edit mode

Tags: tinymce

I have an tinymce editor in admin area where I want to use script tag. With using follows, I am able to use  tag and save it. After that I can see it in database as saved. But the problem is that when I edit the same page again and the editor preloaded with content then it stripped the  tag somehow. So I can not see it and edit it again.

```
valid_children : '+body[style],+body[script]',

extended_valid_elements : '*[*]',
```

So please let me know if there is any way I can stop these script tag stripping off. I have tried to consol log the editor.getContent() but it also show content without  tag whereas I can see it in DB and frontend source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting tripped up by trying to load the closing script tag as part of a string in JavaScript itself.

If you have a closing script (`</script>`) tag in a JavaScript string the interpreter is likely interpreting that as the closing of your script block and not part of the content in the string.  In many cases this will simply break the page's JavaScript completely.

Here is an example in TinyMCE Fiddle that shows the correct way to pass a `</script>` tag in a string:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Fvhaab

For example:

```
tinymce.editors[0].setContent(`
    <p>This is NEW content in TinyMCE!</p>
    <script>
        var x = "test";
        var y = 10;
    </script>
`);
```

...will not work.  If you use this attempt for the closing script tag you will see the editor does not appear at all as that closing script tag prematurely ends the entire section of JavaScript.

Instead you can escape the `/` in the closing script tag:

```
tinymce.editors[0].setContent(`
    <p>This is NEW content in TinyMCE!</p>
    <script>
        var x = "test";
        var y = 10;
    <\/script>
`);
```

...and you will see that the script is loaded into TinyMCE as you would expect.

Comment: thanks but tinymce converted it like this:<p>
<script>// <![CDATA[
        var x = "test";
        var y = 10;
    <\/script>
// ]]></script>
</p> and still not visible in edit mode.

Comment: Can you update the fiddle to make that outcome happen?

Comment: I do not think I can do it on fiddle as fiddle will not save the content of editor and I am having issue in editing(means save the editor with the script and then open it for editing the content again).